# How to mock AxiosResponse?

Tags: node.js, sinon, stub

I am trying to stub the following method in my unit test suite -

```
export const postToServer = async (endpointurl: string, requestBody: any, options: any) => {
    return axios.post(endpointurl, requestBody, options);
};
```

This is my unit test stub -

```
myStub = {
            postToServer: sinon.stub(webapi, 'postToServer').onFirstCall().callsFake(function (request:any, methodType:string, options:any){
                return Promise.resolve();
            }).onSecondCall().rejects('My Error')
        };
```

I am getting this compilation error when trying to run the unit test -

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(request: any, methodType: string, options: any) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(endpointurl: string, requestBody: any, options: any) => Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'AxiosResponse<any, any>'.

301             postToServer: sinon.stub(webapi, 'postToServer').onFirstCall().callsFake(function (request:any, methodType:string, options:any){
```

How do I adjust the stub so as not to get this error? What should I return in the stub function so that it matches AxiosResponse?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to mock Axios is to use [`axios-mock-adapter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter).

[Axios Mocking with React](https://blog.bitsrc.io/axios-mocking-with-reactjs-85d83d51704f)

`axios-mock-adapter` is simple, light, and easy to use. But if you want to roll you own:

- Axios' response schema is [documented here](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema).
- You can specify an `adapter` property in your Axios config. It's value is an `async` function (well, a function returning a promise) that resolves to an Axios response. Adapters (and how to create one) is [documented here](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/main/lib/adapters/README.md). I haven't looked too closely, but I'm willing to bet that this is the mechanism that `axios-mock-adapter` uses.

An example:

- See https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/main/lib/adapters/README.md for details.
- Note that you need to use Axios' [`settle()`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/main/lib/core/settle.js) to resolve the promise.

```
async myAdapter( config ) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    const response = { ... };
    settle(resolve, reject, response);
  });
}

const res = await axios
          .get('http://some.domain.name/path/to/resource', {
            adapter: myAdapter,
          });
```

Now you've short-circuited the request (actual execution of the HTTP request is done by an adapter: you've simply replaced with your own.